# Optimal linear transform in a simplex

Tags: convex-optimization

I'm looking for a simple method to find a linear transform that minimizes
    $$ \text{argmin}_T F(T): T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}
,\ T \ge 0
,\ T \mathbb{1} = c \mathbb{1}
,\ \mathbb{1}^T T = \mathbb{1} $$

i.e. over $m \times n$ matrices $\ge 0$ with row sums all the same and column sums all 1.
(If there's a standard name for this simplex or this problem, please edit.)
$F(T)$ is min${_x}\ f( T x )$ with $f()$ convex but slow; the gradient at the current minimum should be available.
$m$ ~ 20 and $n$ ~ 100, so the method should be $O( m + n )$, not $O( m\,n )$ .
Perhaps line searches that move / clip $T$ along rows / columns ?

(The problem comes from trying to optimize a filter bank a.k.a. overlapping basis;
another application area with many heuristics is feature reduction
in machine learning.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears relatively simple: You have a few linear equality constraints and a few linear inequality constraints, together with a convex objective function. Any optimizer should not have great difficulty with this, even the one in Matlab. If you're looking for specific ones, I believe that Lancelot has ways that specifically deal with constraints like yours.

In general, it would help to know what $f(T)$ is.